# Abash vs. Ignominy

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

From the following two definitions:

> **a•bash** (ə-băshˈ)
>
> *v*.
>      To make ashamed or uneasy; disconcert. See Synonyms at embarrass.

**ig•no•min•y** (ĭgˈnə-mĭnˌē, -mə-nē)

> *n*.
>       Great personal dishonor or humiliation.
>
> *n*.
>      Shameful or disgraceful action, conduct, or character.

Other than the fact that one of them is a verb and the other one a noun, how are they different?

**Can you *abash someone to have an ingonminy*?**

Comment: You mean apart from the fact that disgrace, dishonour, and humiliation have little to do with embarrassment and disconcertedness? I can abash you by telling your new prospective boy-/girlfriend ‘cute’ stories about how you peed the bed until you were 13, but that hardly counts as _disgraceful action_ (neither on my part for telling the story, nor on yours for lacking nocturnal bladder control). Apart from that, _ignominy_ is **very** formal, and _abash_ as an active verb is **very** rare (it’s mostly used in the passive: “He looked slightly abashed” = he looked embarrassed).

Comment: In short, ignominy is a much stronger word than abash.

Comment: An "Ignominy" (a despicable action) generates a strong moral/social condemnation. "Abash" creates an uncomfortable feeling of shame.

Answer (score 1):

To be abashed is a personal feeling, like guilt.  You have to do it on your own.

Ignominy is a social or collective experience. It doesn't matter what you feel, if everyone around you feels you are disgraced, you are disgraced.